# Cannot find type name in schema definitions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I've started using Swashbuckle with Web API.  None of my types are getting rendered correctly in my Swagger UI.  On every method, I see something like this (unrendered):

```
<span class="strong">Typename is not defined!</span>
```

So I investigated, and found this in my Swagger definitions file for many of my methods:

```
{$ref: "#/definitions/Typename", vendorExtensions: {}}
```

`typeName` exists in the definitions listing... but its lower-cased.  They're all lower-cased, but all of the `$ref` are upper-case.

How do I fix this?

**Bounty edit:** More information is available upon request, I'm just not sure what else might be relevant.

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "MyNamespace.Api");
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(
                        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetDataDirectoryPath(), 
                        "MyNamespace.Api.XML"));

                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you paste your Swagger Configuration?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out almost by accident.  For reasons I don't yet understand, I need to make my type names start with a lowercase letter when no one else seems to.

```
c.SchemaId(type => 
{
   var name = type.Name;
   name = $"{ name.Substring(0,1).ToLower() }{ name.Substring(1) }";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your project setting. Sounds like your path could be wrong. Below are setting I use.

```
...swaggerDocsConfig.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
```

and also

```
/// <summary>
/// This is where the generated XML meta documentation are stored.
/// Editable in project settings
/// </summary>
private static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
{
    return string.Format(@"{0}\bin\MrGreen.Game.Service.XML", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the XML comments are working okay.  My methods are annotated with their descriptions in the Swagger UI.

Comment: @ Amy : I second @Jocke . did you try the suggestion ?  In your question you show _c.IncludeXmlComments("MyNamespace.Api.XML")_ => thus you do not specify a path... We use the following construct (similar to @Jocke) : _String.Format(@"{0}\bin\{1}.XML", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, typeof(SwaggerConfig).Namespace);_

Comment: The XML comments are working correctly.  I am generating the filename correctly, but omitted that part of my code to simplify the question.  I'll edit my actual code in, but I assure you, this part is working correctly.